# Spring or thymeleaf does not pass the id parameter to the request?

Tags: spring, request, thymeleaf, http-get

So there is the following form:

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/aliments/edit(id=${aliment.id})}">
    <input th:type="submit" value="Edit"/>                       
</form>
```

Which generates the following html in the browser:

```
<form method="get" action="/aliments/edit?id=1">
    <input value="Edit" type="submit">                       
</form>
```

The problem is that when the form is submited (by clicking the 'Edit' btn) the following request is made (`http://localhost:8080/aliments/edit?` instead of `http://localhost:8080/aliments/edit?id=1`):

[image]

So why the id parameter is not passed to the request?

Comment: When you inspect the DOM, do you see the `action` attribute on the form actually have the id populated?

Comment: If it doesn't, my guess is you don't have a `aliment` object in your view's model with an `'id' property to generate the url properly.

Comment: The strange thing is that the DOM is being populated exactly as written in the question so in DOM there is the correct action: "/aliments/edit?id=1"